# How Prometheus scrape Spring Boot metrics with authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1 with:

```
compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-spring-legacy:1.0.6'
compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.0.6'
```

Spring properties file:

```
management.security.enabled=true
endpoints.prometheus.enabled=true
endpoints.prometheus.sensitive=false
```

In my Prometheus config file I added basic_auth:

```
basic_auth:
    username: username
    password: passw0rd
```

In my [prometheusURL]/targets I keep getting:

> server returned HTTP status 403

**What is the proper way for Prometheus to authenticate each scrape of Spring metrics?**

***EDIT:*** I can pass through Spring Security with this command:

```
curl --cookie "SESSION=7f18cfe7-9a54-4fcf-9662-21d81247c705" http://localhost:8082/management/metrics
```

AFAIK in [prometheus config file](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) we can pass only *basic_auth* or *bearer_token*. There are no other options for headers.